# .htaccess rewrite, rewove filename from URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a domain where I uploaded my html in the root as varg.html, about.html and contact.html. Therefore my URL is `http://vargdesignkollektiv.se/varg.html` but clearly I wan to remove varg.html for my landing page (`http://vargdesignkollektiv.se/`)
I don't really understand if I should use rewrite or redirect in the htaccess nor how to really work it out...

In the htaccess I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) varg.html [L]
```

which works if i write `http://vargdesignkollektiv.se/varg` in the browser.

The about.html I would like to have the URL `http://vargdesignkollektiv.se/about`

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the html extension, you don't want `RewriteRule (.*) varg.html [L]`, which will rewrite everything to `varg.html`.

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html [L]
```